# How do I determine if a class extends another class in Java?

Tags: java

In Java how do I go about determining what classes a class extends?

```
public class A{
}

public class B extends A{
}

public class C extends A{
}

public class D{
}

public class E extends B{
}

public class doSomething{

    public void myFunc(Class cls){
         //need to check that cls is a class which extends A
         //i.e. B, C and E but not A or D
    }
}
```

would `cls.getSuperClass()` do what I need?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `getSuperClass()` approach would fail for `E` since its immediate superclass is not `A`, but `B`. Rather use [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

```
public void myFunc(Class cls){
     //need to check that cls is a class which extends A
     //i.e. B, C and E but not A or D

     if (cls != A.class && A.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
         // ...
     }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution suggested, but I would add that trying to do this is a bit of a "code smell".  You may want to try to find a better way to do it as Martin Broadhurst suggests.

Comment: @Justin: I realize that as well. Unfortunately, the argument is `Class` and the requirement states that `A.class` itself should not pass the check. Best would be to make `A` abstract and apply the strategy pattern, but that requires a *concrete* instance of `A` as argument, not `Class<A>`. I am not sure how that would affect the remnant of OP's design. Maybe the OP has his own valid reasons to choose `Class` as argument. The functional requirement has to be clarified more before we can give better design suggestions.

Comment: Is this being used for an actual business system or school project?

Answer (score 7):

You should try to avoid type checking and instead implement functions in B, C and E that do what you want, have the A and D versions do nothing, and then call that function from within your doSomething class.

If you do type checking it's not very maintainable because when you add new classes you need to change the conditional logic.

It's this problem that classes and overriding are there to prevent.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `Class.getSuperclass()` is exactly what you need.

```
Class<?> c = obj.getClass();
System.out.println(c.getSuperclass() == Some.class);
```

Comment: Do you want == or equals (or does it not matter for class objects)?

Comment: and for class E would I have to iterate up the tree?

Answer (score 1):

If you want compile time checking, you can use Generics (Java 5 and up):

```
public void myFunc(Class<? extends A> cls) {
}
```

Passing in any Class not inherited from A generates a compile time error.