# Java Method for checking if a class extends another class?

Tags: java, extends

Is there any method for checking if a one class extends another class? 
Above code is snippet

```
  File[] fileList = file.listFiles();
        if(fileList != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; ++i){
                ClassName = fileList[i].getName();
                if (fileList[i].isFile() && (Class Extends Class2) && ClassName.endsWith(".class")){
                    String ClassName1 = ClassName.split("\\.")[0];
                    if (!ClassName1.contains("$")){
                        if (packages != null){
                        <Snippet>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have classes `A` and `B`. To determine whether A extends B you can test an instance of `A` with `instanceof` operator. This is sufficient:

```
if((new A()) instanceof B)
    return true;
```

Comment: I feel alittle bit stupid now.. that never even crossed my mind even though i use instanceof for alot. anyway. thanks a ton man

Comment: This approach presupposes `A` always has a default constructor, and that if such a constructor exists it will not do something time-consuming, memory-consuming or plain destructive. :) See [How do I determine if a class extends another class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100281/how-do-i-determine-if-a-class-extends-another-class-in-java) instead.

Comment: @vladr thanks for the link. `isAssignableFrom` is a better approach. but this was what I thought at first sight on the question. I gave default constructor just for example. The OP is supposed to use something like `new A(null, null, 0, "")` etc.

Comment: You can also use A.class.isAssignableFrom to keep from having to instantiate the class.