# Is it possible to check if one class is extending another in java without making instances?

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two `Class<? extends SomeClass>` variables, one obtained from looping the keys of a `HashMap`, we'll call it `A`, and one passed as a parameter, which we'll call `B`. I'd like to see if `B` extends `A`.

So, as I currently understand things, I'd make an instance of `B` (using `createInstance`) and check `instanceof`. But this is not only pretty slow, but cumbersome as classes need an empty constructor.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537183/java-method-for-checking-if-a-class-extends-another-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100281/how-do-i-determine-if-a-class-extends-another-class-in-java), where they discuss `isAssignableFrom` and `getSuperClass`, but `isAssignableFrom` (from what I read there) doesn't work on the same class (SomeClass.isAssignableFrom(SomeClass) ?), and `getSuperClass` doesn't walk up the tree.

Is there a way I can check if `B` extends `A` without creating an instance of `B`?

For example:

```
class SomeClass {}
class ExtendingClassA extends SomeClass {}
class ExtendingClassAB extends ExtendingClassA {}
class ExtendingClassB extends SomeClass {}
boolean ClassExtendsClass(Class<? extends SomeClass> A,Class<? extends SomeClass> B) {
    return A.class instanceof B.class;
}
ClassExtendsClass(SomeClass.class, ExtendingClassA.class); //true
ClassExtendsClass(SomeClass.class, ExtendingClassAB.class); //true
ClassExtendsClass(SomeClass.class, ExtendingClassB.class); //true
ClassExtendsClass(ExtendingClassA.class, ExtendingClassB.class); //false
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem you're describing. If `B extends A`, then `A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class)` would be `true`. Conversely, `B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)` would be `false` _as it should be_, since `B` is not a superclass of `A` (nor is it the same class). Also `B.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class)` would be `true` (same for `A`)

Comment: `getSuperClass` also doesn't walk up the tree by itself, but you can walk up the tree with it.

Comment: @Rogue yes, I'd like to check if `B` extends `A`, but also if `B` is `A`

Comment: @LouisWasserman good idea, would I use a `while` loop for that? Like `while(c = c.getSuperClass())`?

Comment: @Werilous again just consider the converse. `A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class)` would be true if _and only if_ (`B extends A` or `B == A`). There's no reason to not use `#isAssignableFrom`, it's the exact function you're looking for. Similarly, if what you have is _objects_ of `A` and `B`, forgo the `Class<?>`-es entirely and just use `instanceof`

Comment: @Rogue Gotcha, I appreciate that. I don't have objects (instances), I have one class from an `entry` obtained while looping a `HashMap`, and another passed into the parameters of a function. Basically getting the first entry in a `HashMap` where the key extends the class passed to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Generally, check the API (javadoc) of the type you think would be the right place for it. In this case, that'd be `Class` itself, and, luckily, [it's there](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)):

```
Class<?> a = Integer.class;
Class<?> b = Number.class;
System.out.println(b.isAssignableFrom(a));
System.out.println(b.isAssignableFrom(b));
> true
> true
```

> but isAssignableFrom (from what I read there) doesn't work on the same class

You should test that stuff before making assumptions. It works fine.

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate that. I feel dump for not seeing that before haha. And I had assumed that from the discussion, I should have tested it myself.

Comment: Those same people in the discussion would benefit reading [the first line of the method's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-), where it says "Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, ..."

Comment: @Rogue yes I agree, I had missed that same line myself (as you can tell haha)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the getSuperclass method for a class object recursively until you have no more superclasses:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class clazz = C.class;

        System.out.println(clazz.getClass());
        System.out.println(clazz.getSuperclass());
        System.out.println(clazz.getSuperclass().getSuperclass());
        System.out.println(clazz.getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass());
        System.out.println(clazz.getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass());
    }
}
```

the above example will produce

```
class java.lang.Class
class B
class A
class java.lang.Object
null
```

Comment: unwieldy, does not work with interfaces. What's wrong with `isAssignableFrom`?

Comment: Thank you for explaining `getSuperClass` behavior, but could tie this into the question to make it a complete answer?

Comment: @rzwitserloot nothing, I didn't say it was something wrong with it, as a matter of fact, I just learned of it from your response.

Comment: While learning is good, I'd avoid this as an answer personally. `#getSuperClass` will only go one step up, while `#isAssignableFrom` will check the validity of the _relationship_, usually a much more pertinent piece of information.